# how to control bootstrapvue b-table trClass by boolean

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using a b-table from BootstrapVue. However Each row  have a button and
when i click the button i want to change the row background to another color,
i find tbody-tr-class can control but that can not allow the button control

> The Changes and noChange is scss name

```
<b-table :sticky-header="true"
             responsive
             :fields="fields" :items="items" :no-border-collapse="true"
    :tbody-tr-class = "this.changeColor!=false ? 'Changes' : 'noChange'"
    >
      <!--      ref="selectable"-->
      <!--      select-mode="single"-->
      <!--      selectable-->
      <template v-slot:cell(\r)="row">
        <b-dropdown toggle-class="dropdown" size="lg" variant="link" text="..." no-caret>
          <b-dropdown-item @click="onClickButton1(row.item)">buttonName</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

methods

```
data(){
    return{
       changeColor:false;
    }
}
methods:{
    onClickButton1(item){
        this.changeColor = true;
        console.log(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want *all* rows to change color, or just the one row which contains the button that was clicked?

Comment: @Hiws just the one row which contains the button that was clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the color to change on a row to row basis.
You can pass a method to the `tbody-tr-class` prop.
This method will be evaluated per row, and also receives the item for the row as an argument.

This means you can set a boolean flag on your item (`hasChanged` in the example), which will control whether that row should have a different color or not.

What you return from the function, will be added to that rows classes. In the example i use the class [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax), but you can also return a string or an array containing the classes.

I'm using `$set` to add the `hasChanged` property to our item, to ensure that it's reactive. Why that's needed is described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'actions'],
      items: [{
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald'
        },
        {
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw'
        },
        {
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson'
        },
        {
          first_name: 'Jami',
          last_name: 'Carney'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleColor(item) {
      this.$set(item, 'hasChanged', !item['hasChanged'])
    },
    getTrClass(item) {
      return {
        changes: item['hasChanged']
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.changes {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items" :tbody-tr-class="getTrClass">
    <template #cell(actions)="{ item }">
      <b-btn @click="toggleColor(item)">Toggle Color</b-btn>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a great way. I have tried it but it doesn't seem to work for me. I don’t know where I have a setting error

Comment: i find the question my  td style will a background-color so the tr color can not cover

Comment: have a methods can change the tr style what in  choose the td class?

Comment: You can try changing your CSS to target the td instead.
`.changes > td`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what column you want to change in the cell slot. The following code changes the background of all rows.
Also, I created another method to change the background of the row when clicking on the row.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      changeColor: false,
      fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'button'],
      items: [{
          isActive: true,
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald'
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw'
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 89,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson'
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          age: 38,
          first_name: 'Jami',
          last_name: 'Carney'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClickButton1(item) {
      this.changeColor = true
    },
    changeRowVariant(item) {
      item['_rowVariant'] = !item._rowVariant ? "danger" : ""
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }
  }


})
```

```css
.Changes {
  background-color: white;
}

.noChange {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :sticky-header="true" responsive :fields="fields" :items="items" :no-border-collapse="true" :tbody-tr-class="!changeColor ? 'Changes' : 'noChange'" @row-clicked="changeRowVariant">

    <template #cell(button)="row">
        <b-dropdown toggle-class="dropdown" size="lg" variant="link" text="..." no-caret>
          <b-dropdown-item @click="onClickButton1(row.item)">buttonName</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
      </template>
  </b-table>

</div>
```